Can Docker compose watch work for WSL with Ubuntu on a Windows machine?
Coming from this question, I am trying to make Docker compose watch work but it pops an error: /docker-entrypoint.sh: 47: exec: npm: not found. But this is weird since the first stage has "FROM node: 16.13.10-slim".
I have installed Docker Desktop on Windows machine and using WSL 2. The Dockerfile is like this:
# Stage 1
FROM node:16.13.1-slim as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
# add app
COPY . .
ARG REACT_APP_HOST_IP
ARG REACT_APP_HOST_PORT
ENV REACT_APP_HOST_IP=$REACT_APP_HOST_IP
ENV REACT_APP_HOST_PORT=$REACT_APP_HOST_PORT
# start app
RUN npm run build


# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# RUN  chown -R ******* /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN  chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE **** **
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

I've inserted stars (*) to cover some sensitive points.
This is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.9"
services:
  react-nginx-placeholder:
    build:
      context: ./react-nginx
      args:
        REACT_APP_HOST_IP: localhost
        REACT_APP_HOST_PORT: *****
    image: placeholder2/react-nginx-placeholder:1.0
    container_name: react-nginx-placeholder
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "*****:**"
  web:
    build: ./react-nginx
    command: npm start
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./react-nginx/src
          target: /app/src
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./react-nginx/package.json
  placeholder-api:
    build:
      context: ./placeholder-api
    image: placeholder2/placeholder-api:1.0
    container_name: placeholder-api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "*****:****"

Is it possible that I messed up the paths in my docker-compose.yml file? Or because I have two stages in the dockerfile?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Since you're using a multi-stage Dockerfile, you need to rebuild the image whenever any file changes. Not just when package.json changes. I see a lot of people here trying to get docker and docker compose to work both for production deployment and development with the same configuration and it often leads to headaches. My recommendation is to do development without docker if at all possible.

While @DavidMaze's answer addresses one issue with your setup, another issue is that the synchronize definition in the compose file tries to synchronize files into the paths used by the build step. If anything, it should sync into the Nginx directory. After all, it syncs to the running container. But then it assumes that the source files are identical to the files output by the build step. It's a mess :) The synchronize part should be deleted and the image rebuilt whenever a change is made. Or you should move away from using Nginx and instead use Node in the running container.

@HansKilian The paths shown in the web service are put by me. I don't know if they are actually correct. Could you elaborate what I could have done instead?

I can only repeat my recommendation from my first comment: Keep your setup simple. Get some experience with Docker and Docker Compose and only then add complexity. Right now, you're trying to get the most complicated setup possible to work. Develop outside Docker. Build your images using docker build. And only use compose for orchestration.

I'd love if it worked, but no luck yet. So, I will just run the react project locally with npm install for libraries and npm start to start the dev server. Will come back to Docker later to learn a few things.
Thanks for the tips!

When you have a multi-stage build, only the last stage is actually run.  So while you did start from a node image, your final stage is built FROM nginx, and only contains the Nginx server and your static application.
It looks like this has a simple solution, though.  In your Compose file you have an override
command: npm start

And if you just delete that, you'll use the CMD from the image instead.  For many common use cases you don't need a Compose command: at all.

(The nginx base image already has EXPOSE 80 and CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"], and you don't need to repeat these lines in your own Dockerfile.  You probably don't need the RUN chmod either.)

Hello and sorry for the delayed response. I delete the command just as you said, but when I change something in my code, nothing happens in the UI. Is there anything else that I should do to make it work? In my shell, I get a message that "Configuration complete; ready for start up". The web service seems to be running OK in the Docker Desktop (green icon).
